# How can I obtain reproducible results using Keras during development?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I followed this [link](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development) but I can't set `PYTHONHASHSEED=0` ,or `PYTHONHASHSEED=0`, it won't work. My code is as follows：

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random as rn
sd = 1
np.random.seed(sd)
rn.seed(sd)
config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
from keras import backend as K
tf.set_random_seed(sd)
sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=config)
K.set_session(sess)
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'
```

Every time I ran the code, it gave different results. My environment consists of

- Keras 2.2.4
- with tensorflow-CPU 1.14.0 as backend.
- python 3.7
- windows 10

Can anyone help me get a reproducible result?

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably to be honest, apparently Keras devs don't seem concerned about that (see [this issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2280)).

You can find some hacks to **maybe** do it over there, been trying most of them on collab with no luck though, sorry.